# Are these productions correct?

Tags: compiler-construction

Chomsky transformation:

```
1) A--> aAb

2) A--> bAa

3) A--> ε
```

Applying the Chomsky Normala Form, are these productions correct?

```
S--> aAbB | bBaA

A--> a

B--> b
```

Thanks in advance 
Any help will be highly appreciated

Joachim

Comment: this should really be on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the standard definition of [Chomsky normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form) the answer is no.

E.g. `S -> aAbB` contains non-terminal as well as terminal symbols on the right hand side which is not allowed.